# In Finder, when I change extension it adds .txt to end instead of changing it

Tags: macos, finder

I have a `file.txt`

I want to change it to `file.faa`

I click on the file in `Finder` and change it to `file.faa`, it says it changed it but then when I `Get Info` it says `file.faa.txt` so I need to manually go in and change it.  Super annoying.  I can mv in the terminal but sometimes I just want to click it.

**Does anyone know how to stop this**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to stop this?

I always turn on the "Show all filename extensions" in the Finder -> Preferences.  Obviously you could turn it on, tweak the name of the file and then turn it back off if you didn't want to run with this setting all of the time.